# ESP8266 SSDP - Not showing on Windows?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu, ssdp

I've got the ESP8266SSDP library running on my NodeMCU, and have it configured like so:

```
SSDP.setSchemaURL("test.xml");
SSDP.setHTTPPort(80);
SSDP.setName("Addressable Strip");
SSDP.setSerialNumber("001788102201");
SSDP.setURL("index.html");
SSDP.setModelName("ESP8266");
SSDP.setModelNumber("929000226503");
SSDP.setModelURL("http://www.google.com");
SSDP.setManufacturer("Nobody");
SSDP.setManufacturerURL("http://www.google.com");
SSDP.setDeviceType("upnp:rootdevice");
if(SSDP.begin()){
  Serial.println("SSDP started");
}
```

The above will not show up in Windows for some reason, however I download SSDPTester for my phone and I can see the following when it is searching for devices

```
9 Jan 2017 9:15:15 am: Packet received from 192.168.1.123:1900 :
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
EXT:\r\n
CACHE-CONTROL: max-age=1200\r\n
SERVER: Arduino/1.0 UPNP/1.1 ESP8266/929000226503\r\n
USN: uuid:38323636-4558-4dda-9188-cda0e6cd87f1\r\n
ST: upnp:rootdevice\r\n
LOCATION: http://192.168.1.123:80/description.xml\r\n
\r\n
```

Does anyone know why the doesn't show up in Windows?

Comment: is this the discovery thing that you need to run Apple's Bonjour for Windows to use?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I think SDDP is different to bonjour!

Comment: What does "doesn't show up in Windows" mean? Where do you expect it to show up?

Comment: It should show up under the network discovery section in Windows

Answer (score 1):

```
SSDP.setDeviceType("upnp:rootdevice");
```

Modify the above line to the following:

```
SSDP.setDeviceType("urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:DimmableLight:1");
```

Answer (score 0):

On your NodeMCU, be sure to send a NOTIFY message on startup and periodically in order for the Windows control point to detect and list the device.